# All statically assigned addresses, but dhcpcd still runs?

Tags: debian, dhcp, ip-address, static-ip, debian-wheezy

I have a VM (on ESXi 5.1.0) running Debian Wheezy (7.0).

eth0 has a statically assigned address. eth1 *was* DHCP-assigned, and now I want to make it static.

Here is my old `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0 eth1
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0 eth1
iface eth0 inet static
 address 10.2.1.77
 broadcast 10.2.1.255
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 pointopoint 10.2.1.1

iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

And here is my new `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0 eth1
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0 eth1
iface eth0 inet static
 address 10.2.1.77
 broadcast 10.2.1.255
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 pointopoint 10.2.1.1

iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.1.0.254
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.1.0.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

When I reboot, I can see `dhcpcd` try to renew my lease for my old DHCP-assigned address, and succeed. And then it overwrites `/etc/resolv.conf`, which *should* contain 8.8.8.8 but does not. eth1 does have the correct (static) address, however.

What am I doing wrong here? I don't want to disable `dhcpcd` outright. In the near future I might switch eth1 back to DHCP, or add a third DHCP-assigned interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a limitation in `dhcpcd5` - it enables DHCP on all interfaces (all or nothing). I fixed this by switching to `isc-dhcp-client` which is more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

Run (as root):

`update-rc.d -f dhcpd remove`

If you want to re-enable it in the future,

`update-rc.d dhcpd defaults`

NOTE: Removing it from rc.d will disable it on all interfaces.  Restoring it will enable on all interfaces.

Comment: So it's all interfaces or no interfaces?

Is there a way to use an alternative dhcp client?

Comment: As far as I am aware, yes.  I don't know much about Linux, sadly.

Comment: So I was using the `dhcpcd5` package. Looks like there are lots of alternatives: `dhcpcd`, `udhcpc`, `isc-dhcp-client` and `pump` are some of them.

Comment: Switched to `isc-dhcp-client` and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using dhcpcd (the client daemon, most people here are confusing it with DHCP and DHCPd which is different), then add the following text on the bottom of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

```
static
interface eth0
static ip_address=172.16.0.5/24
static routers=172.16.0.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
```

Of course remember to replace the IP info with your network details.

Comment: This was helpful reminding me that I needed to do the same thing on `wlan0` on my Raspberry Pi when I wanted to switch to manual/static IP on Raspbian Jessie, which runs DHCPd by default. No need to uninstall it completely as long as you configure `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The [man page for dhcpcd](https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcpcd.conf.5.html) tells us:

> denyinterfaces pattern
>
> ```
>          When discovering interfaces, the interface name must not match
>          pattern which is a space or comma separated list of patterns
>          passed to fnmatch(3).
> ```

To stop dhcpcd from operating on an interface(s), you can ask it to leave the interface alone by adding the a line to /etc/dhcpcd.conf.

in the OPs case this would be:

```
denyinterfaces eth0
```

This should stop dhcpcd messing with you on that specific interface while leaving dhcpcd enabled. This also lets you keep your interface configuration in /etc/network/interfaces. The other option is using what Ariffer suggested (Using /etc/dhcpcd.conf to do your config instead of /etc/network/interfaces.)

Answer (score 1):

Works on debian 11:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network 
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=no
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was the easiest way on nocloud image

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the service.  https://serverfault.com/questions/32438/disable-a-service-from-starting-at-all-runlevels

The preferred method would be to update the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` file for the device removing the dhcp line (or altering it to false)

Unfortunately I'm not in front of my linux machine right now so I can't pull the exact configuration for you.

Comment: Unfortunately `/etc/sysconfig` does not exist on Debian. Or at least on my install.

Comment: I should also mention that doing both wont hurt anything unless you plan on adding a NIC that will use DHCP.

Comment: My appologies.  I've only ever encountered this problem when using network manager on the command line.  After a quick google it appears those files are part of NetworkManager configuration opposed to what you are using.